# Random quote machine, API will not return a new quote

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So i build entire project in Visual Studio Code, I tested it on Chrome and Explorer and it works, it retrieves a new quote and an author with the press of a button, great i thought time to put it into codepen, nope, doesn’t work. Here is what happens, i am using http://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/ to get my quotes, when you put this into a browser you see what it retrieves
http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1
the problem seems that on firefox if you enter this you will get a quote, however, if you enter the same link(note that not refresh the page but use the same link) you will get the same quote, in chrome, however, it will give you a new quote, sooooo i tried to see if it would work if I used codepen on chrome, and it didnt work at all because on chrome codepen the api call wouldnt even retrieve any data. here is a function I am using right now.
my code for getting new function looks like this.

```
getRandomQuote = event =>{
    fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if(data[0].content && data[0].title && data[0].link){
          let {quote} = this.state;
          let quoteData=data[0];
          quote.content = quoteData.content;
          quote.link = quoteData.link;

          quote.title = quoteData.title;


        this.setState({
          quote,
            isLoaded:true

          })
      }
      else{
          return console.error('No Quote :(')
      }

    })



  }
```

here is a link for my codepen:https://codepen.io/russiandobby/pen/OqaxWW?editors=1111
How can I get it to retrieve new cote?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I feel stupid, after some research i found that it seems that all i had to do is change my request a little bit from

```
fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1')
```

to

```
 fetch('https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1', {cache: "reload"})
```

after i did that, it started to work on all browsers and retriving new quotes, i been banning m had for 2 hours and all it took is less then 1 line to fix itT_T